# Delete all files in directory except in one subdirectory

Tags: windows, scripting, cmd, command-prompt

I have this script:

```
    forfiles /p "C:\Hello" /m *.* /s /d -5 /c "cmd /c if /i not @path==C:\Hello\Dontdelete del @file"
```

I'm trying to delete every file older than 5 days in C:\Hello except for files that are in C:\Hello\Dontdelete or any directory within this path.

Currently everything is getting deleted when I use the above script.

Thanks!

Comment: You spelled `Hello` wrong the second time

Comment: That's not the mistake, I just copied it wrong here. It still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fundamental problem is that `@path` is the **full** pathname - including the filename+extension, and quoted and `@file` is the filename+extension, also quoted. In consequence, the `if` statement as constructed can't be manipulated to work as anticipated.

Here's a way to get it working (I've made a few changes to suit my system which should be easy to manipulate to suit yours)

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
forfiles /p "%sourcedir%" /m *.* /s /d -6 /c "cmd /c call %cd%\selectdel @PATH"
GOTO :EOF
```

I set up `selectdel` as a batch in my current directory. No doubt it would be fine on the path, or simply forced as I have with the `%cd%\`.

**selectdel.bat**

```dos
@echo off
setlocal
if /i not "%~dp1"=="%sourcedir%\Dontdelete\" echo DEL %1
GOTO :eof
```

Obviously, I've simply `echo`ed the `del` command - in case of accidents...

Comment: It's not a one-line solution but it works. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

I do not know much about it, but I think you should make a lopping for every 5 days, the script did a check to see if there are files in the folder C :/ Hello, if yes, the script clears, if not, it does nothing. Search about it.

Comment: The script does more than what I want it to. It doesn't recognize an exception that I made.